# Getting a user's marketing source from Google Analytics

Tags: api, google-analytics, facebook-marketing-api

I'm a backend developer who has no experience with Google Analytics, but I've a requirement to find a way to collect the Marketing Medium/Source for each user from Google Analytics and save it in my database, I've been searching and looking how to get it from an API request but I didn't find a way yet, could you guys help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Google Python API to fetch the Google Analytics data. You can read more [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/analytics/v3).

Medium and Source information can be found out by using the dimension **ga:sourceMedium**
You can find more info about dimensions and metrics [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=traffic_sources&jump=ga_source)

Following which you can setup a daily script and fetches the data from your Google Analytics account and dumps data into csv which you can successively load into your database using libraries such as psycopg2.